# The best and safest way to run Jenkins

Tags: security, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Run Jenkins in Docker or in standalone...?
Which is the safest and stable way to run Jenkins on a CI server `(Tomcat, Docker)`  ?

Comment: why do you think either of them with make a difference w.r.t security?

Comment: maybe  Jenkins is more stable there  and more harder to hack.. :D anyway thanks for your time